# field properties from prime subfield

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Given a field $F_{p^n}$ with $char(F)=p$ and $p$ prime. 
And thus our main misunderstanding: Why is the arithmetic in $F_{p^n}$ modular p? Why is it that it's prime field $F_{p}$ forces upon $F_{p^n}$ this particular arithmetic? 
I have seen that $Z/pZ \cong$ primefield of $F_{p^n}$. But i doesn't convince that the binary operation + on $F_{p^n}$ is mod p.

EDIT: the example earlier included is deleted as it weren't that important for the problem itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathbb F$ is a field (or more general a ring) with $\text{char}({\mathbb F})=p>0$ then for each $x\in\mathbb F$ we have: $$\stackrel{\overbrace{p\text{ times}}}{x+\cdots+x}=\stackrel{\overbrace{p\text{ times}}}{\left(1_{\mathbb F}+\cdots+1_{\mathbb F}\right)}.x=0_{F}.x=0_{F}$$

This works in field $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ since $\text{char}({\mathbb F_{p^n}})=p>0$.

---

The information $\text{char}(\mathbb F)=p$ is actually saying us that the unique homomorphims $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb F$ has ideal $\langle p\rangle$ as its kernel. Based on that we find: $$\stackrel{\overbrace{p\text{ times}}}{1_{\mathbb{F}}+\cdots+1_{\mathbb{F}}}=f\left(\stackrel{\overbrace{p\text{ times}}}{1+\cdots+1}\right)=f\left(p\right)=0_{F}$$

Comment: But why p=0?....

Comment: the characteristic is by definition the smallest nonnegative integer that generates the kernel of unique homomorphism $f:\mathbb Z\to F$. So $p\in\mathbb Z$ is sent by $f$ to $0_F$. Actually we have: $1_F+\cdots1_F=f(p)=0_F$.

Comment: i've just read that $F_{p^n} \cong (Z/pZ)^n$ and that's why every element has additive order p. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Where did you read that? It's not true. E.g. look at $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^2$ and observe that e.g. element $(0,1)$ has no multiplicative inverse. So this ring is not a field.

Comment: You can also have a look [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/finitefields.pdf)  at theorem 1.5.

Comment: It is true that as an additive group (only), $\Bbb F_{p^n}\cong(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^n$. Not multiplicatively, and I don’t think that that was OP’s intent.

Comment: @Lubin Yes, you are right. In my critics I was a bit too much focused on fields/rings.